# How to solve error "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" from javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing chrome extension and I want to get HTML content from URL, and I have a code as below:

```
function getContentHTML() {
    var theUrl = 'http://tuoitre.vn/The-gioi/620269/my-cong-bo-anh-ve-tinh-nga-ban-ten-lua-vao-ukraine.html';
    $.ajax({
        url: theUrl,
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "html",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            document.write(data);
        }
    });
}
```

My problem is: Some website I can get HTML content but some website I can not get HTML  content and show error is "Access-Control-Allow-Origin". I'm also follow in google but I can not solved.

Comment: Do you have the host in permissions in your manifest?

Answer (score 0):

This means that the site doesn't allow your page's origin to query its content via `ajax`. This is disallowed by default because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), but can be enabled by the site owner via [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/).

If the site doesn't allow your origin to access it, you cannot solve it client-side. You'd have to do something like query the information from *your* server (which would in turn use server-side code to query it from the other site, and then return it to you).

Answer (score -1):

there are sites on which server will not accept requests from third-party domains. This problem has no solution.

Comment: Not for an extension. Extensions have the power to ignore this limitation.